# tying a UISearchBar into an action

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

To let you know from the beginning, I am a newbie at iPhone development, and I have taken an a monstrous task.

First of all, I am writing an application that allows to you to online shop. We have an affiliate account with a known online shopping website, are trying to tie our app into searching that site, and putting the results into a table, with hyperlinks to the site, etc.

But first problems first, one thing at a time:

In Interface Builder, I have a Search Bar, and an outlet connected to the search bar. I also have an IBAction made just to take the text that is entered into the search bar, storing it into a variable, and then searching this website (yes, that's a lot of stuff for an action).

Because I am so new at this process with IB, how do I connect the Search Bar with the IBAction? I know, stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a specific SEARCH button, set your View Controller as the delegate for UITextField and implement your action on

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Code here...
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to declare the protocol in your interface file too

```
@interface ... : ... <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Once that's done, everytime the GO/SEARCH key is pressed on the keyboard, it will call the method above.

[EDIT]
Here's the apple Doc for your reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set your view controller as the search bar's delegate in IB (or programmatically), and implement the [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol to define actions for your search bar.

As a beginner, you should familiarize yourself with the delegate pattern, since a lot of the iOS SDK relies on it (the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html) is a good place to start).

**Update**

You need to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods in your search bar's `delegate`. For example, if your search bar is a property of `MyViewController`, you probably want to have this line in `MyViewController`'s implementation:

```
[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
```

It's as simple as that; now, as long as you have those methods implemented in `MyViewController`, they will automatically get called when the related action occurs.